# Save a variable in react until the browser is open

Tags: reactjs, cookies, local-storage, session-cookies

The question may seem to be confusing, so let me explain, i'm building a react app that's basically about traveling and shows each cities tourist attraction by the city that the user has chosen, but the problem is all of the pages are filtered by the city name that has been chosen in header, so what i'm trying to do save the slug attribute that is unique to each city and pass it to my api call, but i want it to only show as long as the browser isn't closed, for example if user chooses the city in home page and goes to another page i should still have that slug, and i don't want to change my routes, so the option to change my routes is crossed for example like below:

```
www.example.com/NY
or 
www.example.com/NY/tour/central park
```

I want to keep my routes like before but still have the slug `NY`, so my routes look like below

```
www.example.com
or 
www.example.com/tour/central park
```

So how can i accomplish that?

Comment: You want to store that NY value until the browser isn't closed ?

Comment: yeah, basically i want to have that, until the browser is closed

Comment: You can use loccalstorage to save that value

Comment: it keeps the value even after the browser is closed

Comment: Sorry, my bad! you should use sessionstorage for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to save achieve this.

// Store value

```
localStorage.setItem("slug", "NY");
```

// Retrieve value

```
localStorage.getItem("slug");
```